# owl.data('owlCarousel') return null

Tags: owl-carousel

I placed the owl.data('owlCarousel') right after the following code but it is not working. It returns null.

```
    owl= $("#owl-me");
    owl.owlCarousel({
        items : 8, //10 items above 1000px browser width
    });
```

Could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access the data before the carousel has had a chance to initialize. Try adding an event handler for when the carousel is initialized. If you're using owl carousel 2, something like this:

```
$('#owl-me').on({

        'initialized.owl.carousel': function () {
              //your code here
         }

    }).owlCarousel(options);
```